# How to Call LAPACK from C in MacOS?

Tags: c, xcode, lapack

I am using XCode to develop in C on MacOS.  It's a terminal application.

How can I call BLAS and LAPACK from C in MacOS?

Comment: Do BLAS and LAPACK come in library form or are they stand-alone programs?

Comment: What did you try so far? Are you asking about how to include headers or do you have problem a compilation time to link the libraries?